# Searching HTML content in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am storing html data in elastic search. On search of word or phrase if records having match data then list out all match records inclusive  of  pre tag and post tag for the match words to be highlighted. Below is the example of my query.

< p>This is paragrpah tag< span>This is span tag</ span>< /p>

Search word : "span tag"

What query I should pass to get list of records that match the search word.

Comment: do you want to search for `"span tag"` in `< p>This is paragrpah tag< span>This is span tag</ span>< /p>` ?

Comment: Yes I want to search "span tag" but it should also add pre tags and post tag for the searched words. like ......
< p>This is paragrpah tag< span>This is <h1 class="searched">span tag</h1></ span>< /p>